# Replace Switch-Case to select Class properties and filter with LINQ and reflection C#

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, switch-statement

I have a `Product` class with several properties:

```
public class Product
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Category { get; set; }
   public string ProdCountry { get; set; }
}
```

Now suppose I have `var products = List<Product>` and I want to filter some specific property value that I do not know in advance. All the `{ propertyName, propertyValue }` pairs have to be matched (so AND relation):

```
Dictionary<string, string> properties = GetPropertiesFromClient(); //Key = propertyName, Value = propertyValue

List<Product> products = GetProductList();

foreach(var property in properties)
{
   switch (property.Key)
   {
       case "Name": products = products.Where(p => p.Name == property.Value); 
                    break;

       case "Category": products = products.Where(p => p.Category == property.Value);
                        break;

       case "ProdCountry": products = products. Where(p => p.ProdCountry == property.Value);
                           break;
   }
}
```

The method `GetPropertiesFromClient()` always return a `Dictionary<string, string>` where I do not know in advance which property and how many are stored.

Is there any shortcut that avoids me to use a `switch case`? Something like:

```
foreach(var property in properties)
{
    products = products.Where(t => t.GetType().GetProperty(property.Key).GetValue(t, null) == property.Value);
}
```

This code is supposed to work (logically) but I get an exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object
>   GetValue(System.Object, System.Object[])' method, and this method
>   cannot be translated into a store expression.

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Your error suggests `products` is an `IQueryable<Product>` instead of a `List<Product>`. Which is it?

Comment: LINQ to Entities can't convert getting value of property via reflection into a valid SQL expression. So, you can't achieve your goal using reflection. Try dynamically constructing EntitySQL or LINQ expression.

Comment: Yes it is a IQueryable<Product>

Answer (score 0):

With `property` being an object, it's trying to translate the `get` accessor to SQL.

Try executing the getter locally and saving the structural value. Then compare with the local variable instead of the property object:

```
foreach(var property in properties)
{
   var x = property.Value;
   switch (property.Key)
   {
       case "Name": products = products.Where(p => p.Name == x); 
                    break;
       //...
    }
}
```